# How do I know that UpdateOneAsync failed (from UpdateResult)?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to upsert one document into MongoDb. Pretty straightforward but what do I check (beyond the presence of an exception) to know that it failed?

Code:

```
public async Task<UpdateResult> UpdateDocument<T>(
    string sConnectionString, 
    string sDatabaseName, 
    string sCollectionName, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, 
    UpdateDefinition<T> update,
    bool bUpsert,
    System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
{
    ConnectToDb(sConnectionString);

    IMongoDatabase db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(sDatabaseName);

    IMongoCollection<T> collection = db.GetCollection<T>(sCollectionName);

    return await collection.UpdateOneAsync<T>(filter, update, new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = bUpsert }, cancellationToken);
}

private void ConnectToDb(
    string sConnectionString
    )
{
    if(sConnectionString != _sConnectionString)
    {
        _mongoClient = null;
        _mongoClient = new MongoClient(sConnectionString);

        _sConnectionString = sConnectionString;
    }
}
```

And then the code that calls it:

```
try
{
    MongoDB.Driver.UpdateResult updateResult = await _db.UpdateDocument<Models.NodeBoardModel>(
        _dbSettings._sURLMongoDbConnectionString,
        _dbSettings._sDatabasename, Constants.NodeBoardCollectionName,
        node => node.Id == boardToServerData._request.Id,
        MongoDB.Driver.Builders<Models.NodeBoardModel>.Update.Set(node => node.RemoteBoard, dbboardmodel),
        true,
        stoppingToken
        );

    bool bAcked = updateResult.IsAcknowledged;
    if(updateResult.
}
catch(AggregateException aggEx)
{
    Models.Errors errors = null;

    errors = Helpers.ProcessAggregateException(
        aggEx, 
        Models.eError.UPSERTREMOTEBOARD
        );

    _logger.LogError(errors.GetErrorModel()._sSpecificErrorMessage);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Models.Errors errors = null;

    errors = Helpers.ProcessException(
        ex, 
        Models.eError.UPSERTREMOTEBOARD
        );

    _logger.LogError(errors.GetErrorModel()._sSpecificErrorMessage);
}
```

It looked very simple (just look for the exception) until I saw UpdateResult. With not much context about what to do with it:

http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateResult.htm

So even if I don't get an exception could it still have failed? I'm guessing if IsAcknowledged is false then I have failed. Is there a case where failure could have occured when IsAcknowledged is true?

Comment: The point of `UpdateResult` is to tell you how many documents matched the expression you have and how many were modified as a result ( yes the same result class applies to multi document updates as well ). These numbers can differ considering that there are various conditions where a specified update may not result in any data actually being changed. Even in the case where nothing is matched **this is not an error**. An **error** is when something really bad happened. This might be a "network error", or it might be you tried to do something illegal.

Comment: Errors of course are **raised exceptions**. So really you should **always** be looking at **both**. 1. The "update result" in order to see you actual matched and *possiblly* modified what you expected. 2. The "thrown errors" because that is when something actually was an exception. Not matching a document or modifying nothing is simply **not an exception**. Nor should it be. Your code is responsible for checking things worked as you expected them to.